# Passing PHP variable via AJAX to PHP variable in another DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, ajax

I've been working on this for a whole day but think I'm getting confused on the various methods available while I learn AJAX.   I want my website to display the results of Python script. I can do that.

The problem is the script's results change randomly (it's the status of my garage door) and my site is clunky if the garage door's status changes.  Usually the user has to keep reloading the page to get a current status.  I'm trying to have the DIV that shows the status to update every 5 seconds thus showing the new status.

The Python script takes about 4 seconds to run, so I want to keep calling it as a function and pass it as a DIV on my site where I want to display the results.

If possible, one PHP file (index.php).  Here is the skeleton of what I'm looking to do.  My get_status function works, but I'm at a loss on the rest of it.

Thank you.

EDIT:   Code updated with minor tweaks spotted by the commenters.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
    function get_status(){
        $status = shell_exec('python /path/to/garage_door/myq-garage.py status');  //Equals either 'Open' or 'Closed'
        echo $status;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    var java_status = <?php echo json_encode(get_status) ?>;

    // I have no idea how to pass a variable from PHP thru javascript to PHP on the 
    // same page.  Trying to pass on results of get_status function every 5 seconds.

    setInterval(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php"
            type: "POST"
            dataType: "json"
            data: ({status: java_status}),
            success: function(data){
                $("#status_div").html(data);
            }
        })

    }, 5000);
</script>

<div id="status_div">
    <?php
        $new_status = json_decode(data);
    ?>        

    // I have no idea how to get that status variable here.
    The Garage Door Status is:  <?php 
        echo $new_status;
    ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: You do not need any code in `#status_div` at all. You should parse `data` in your success function and place the necessary portion in `#status_div`

Comment: Is your Python code returning JSON?

Comment: Tink, tink, tink. Is this thing on?

Comment: If this is your HTML it is not valid.

Comment: HI Jay,  The Python returns text strings.     In #status_div, I have no idea on how to parse 'data' in the success function and place in in #status_div.    As for the invalid HTML, is that the improper comment you're referring to?

Comment: echo's belong in `<body></body>` and anything else being printed on screen.

Comment: This is on an apache web server.   I have NOT yet looked at my browsers developer tools, but I'm afraid my attempts are so shotty I'm not really passing much to look at.     I'm not getting any errors.  As I tinker I either get a blank page, or a rendered page with no status displayed in the DIV.

Comment: btw @Mike if you want to address someone directly, use the @ symbol as I did here for you, followed by their name and a space. They may not always be present to see if you are addressing them.

Comment: @Fred -ii-I neglected <body> tags in post, but adding them in my actual php file doesn't change anything.

Comment: `json_decode(data)` that alone should be throwing you an undefined constant error. You can't use `data` from your JS like that into a PHP function.

Comment: Youve declared the function `get_status()` but i dont see you calling it anywhere.

Comment: @Fred -ii- The page seems to be rendering.  I'm not getting any errors.  Where shoudl I be looking for them?

Comment: @Kisaragi Good catch.   The code in the OP is a mocked up version of much larger code.  I trimmed it down to just the basics of trying to send the variable.   I missed that I'm not calling the function.   I added it here, but no dice:   var java_status = <?php echo json_encode(get_status()) ?>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly you have to have valid HTML and you don't need to send the PHP script any parameters. In addition, you need to separate your PHP from the rest of the code, else you will get back all of the markup in your AJAX response:

PHP Script - *php_python.php*

```
<?php
    function get_status(){
        $status = shell_exec('python /path/to/garage_door/myq-garage.py status');  //Equals either 'Open' or 'Closed'
        echo $status;
    }
    get_status(); // execute the function
?>
```

HTML Page - *index.php (note the use of a document ready handler because the script is at the top of the page)*

You also need to separate `<script>` tags, using one to load the jQuery library and another to describe your JavaScript functions.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ // you need a document ready handler if you put the script at the top of the page
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "php_python.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#status_div").html('The Garage Door Status is: ' + data);
                    }
                })

            }, 5000);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div id="status_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're just learning jQuery's AJAX [here are some basic tips for setting it up and trouble-shooting problems](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: Thank you!  With some modification I am able to get this working.  In php_python.php nothing was running because the function wasn't getting called, so I just commented out the function lines while leaving the $status variable creation and echoing of it.    Thank you for explaining some of your reasoning.  That helps a lot and some important things I wasn't aware of.

Comment: There is always more than one way to skin the proverbial cat. Another thing you could've done is add a line, `get_status();` right after you close the function bracket as I have done in the updated code. There is really no sense in a function if all you're doing is executing 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page and named it status.php

status.php include these code:

```
    $status = shell_exec('python /path/to/garage_door/myq-garage.py status');        
    echo $status;
```

Make another page index.php and include-

```
<div id="status_div">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "status.php",

            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data){
                $("#status_div").html(data);
            }
        })

    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to try that.   I have to drive somewhere and will try it later tonight and report back.   Just seeing that has taught me some things I never would have figured out on my own.

Comment: It should work if i understand properly what you want... thanks

Comment: I just tried that, but it get a blank page for both status.php and index.php.    On index.php I caught a problem on your 3rd line.  I've changed it to:    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">

Comment: In status.php you should add those code in php tag

and you have to run the index.php to see the status. yes that was an syntax error..

Comment: what result you get when you run the status.php ?? if its blank then your shell_exec() is not working

Comment: On status.php I forgot to change the path to the python script to my actual path.  Once I fixed that, status.php does properly display the status from the script.   But, index.php comes up blank.  So, I put some test text in between the DIV tags and that text does load.   Looks like either something is preventing the rest of the page from running or variable isn't making it through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax, you can make your life very easy:

function_status.php:

```
<?php
function get_status(){
        $status = shell_exec('python /path/to/garage_door/myq-garage.py status');     //Equals either 'Open' or 'Closed'
        return $status; //avoid echo in such functions, try to not produce side effects
    }
```

ajax_server.php:

```
<?php
require_once("function_status.php");
echo get_status();
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once("function_status.php");
?>
<html>
<body>
<div id="status">
<?php echo get_status(); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">

( //run function immediatly
  function($){ //in this anonymous function, $ is always jQuery
     function updateStatus(){
         $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_server.php"
            type: "POST"
            dataType: "json"
            data: ({status: 1}),
            success: function(data){
                $("#status").html(data);
            }
        });
     }

     //first call it onload
     $(function(e){
        updateStatus();
     }

     //and then every 5 seconds
     setInterval(updateStatus, 5000);
     );
   }

)//run function immediatly
(jQuery); //pass parameter jQuery to immediate execution of anonymous function



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it is not a very clean way, and i used the `<?php echo get_status(); ?>` only, because your python script takes 4 seconds, so you would have no status for the first 4 seconds.
else you could change it to index.html and have a nicely seperated html and php, if you anyway want to populate the html with ajax.
if you really want to hack it into one file, you need an

```
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
echo get_status();
}else{
//output the html around the whole thing
}
```

Comment: Since the AJAX call is asynchronous it doesn't matter how long it takes for the script to echo a value, no?

Comment: True - but how does that affect the AJAX call?

Comment: if your python script takes 4 seconds, it takes 4 seconds to load the page initially , and every update request takes 4 seconds too.

asynchonisity means other javascript code doesn't have to wait until the request is done, but the request itself is not sped up.

t=0: get request
t=4: page loaded, updateStatus called 1. time, interval of 5s started
t=8: response of 1. call of updateStatus arrives
t=9: Interval starts 2. call of updateStatus
t=13: response of 2. call updateStatus
t=14: Interval starts 3. call of updateStatus
....

Comment: If the PHP script is separate the page loads immediately and then an AJAX request is made. 4 seconds after that you should get a response.

Comment: yes, but for the first 4 seconds you see a page with no status. That's your choice. Either fast loaded page with no status, or a slow loaded page with status. If the request was faster, i would seperate it.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I learned some things here.  I do agree timing of how/when the site loads might take some adjustment.   The good thing is, where this is displayed will be mixed in with many other things being monitored, so if this one portion of the pages takes a little longer to load, it should be okay.